# How can i get my output to convert as dictionary/json object?

Tags: python-3.x

I am working with an API and everything "works" but it comes back as the following

```
    with requests.Session() as s:

        resp = s.post(url, json={"user": "s153152","password": "password123"}, headers=headers, verify=False)
        print(resp.status_code)

        timestamp = None
        deleteData = False
        fields = None

        resp2 = s.post(url2, json={
            "timestamp" : timestamp,
            "deleteData" : deleteData,
            "fields":fields}, headers=headers2, verify=False, timeout=45)

        resp2 = resp2.text
        print(type(resp2))
        for data in resp['hostName']:
            print(data)
```

resp2 is a string, it is possible to convert the output to a dictionary?

Expection: Json output so that i can call each individual value from key/pair

When i try the following i am getting jsondecode error:

```
resp3 = resp2.text
data = json.loads(resp3)
print(data)
print(type(resp2))
for i in data['hostName']:
    print(i)
```

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Expected data to be returned, however the format of the variable is a string

[")]}',", '    {
"newestTimestamp": "2016-08-29T13:43:59.0000001",
"data": [
{
"hostName": "MULBERRY",
"ipAddresses": [
"192.168.146.131"
],
"locationsWithMatches": "538",
"locationsWithUnprotectedMatches": "93",
"totalMatches": "9706",
"totalUnprotectedMatches": "1319",
"lastSearchTime": "2015-08-11T18:59:45.927",
"id": -2147479361,
"changedTimestamp": "2015-08-11T18:59:45.927",
"dataTypes": [
{
"count": 914,
"name": "Social Security Number"
},
{
"count": 1237,
"name": "Credit Card Number"
}
]
},
{
"hostName": "DYCKMAN",
"ipAddresses": [
"192.168.124.184"
],
"locationsWithMatches": "592",
"locationsWithUnprotectedMatches": "93",
"totalMatches": "11470",
"totalUnprotectedMatches": "1782",
"lastSearchTime": "2015-08-31T05:53:05.28",
"id": -2147479360,
"changedTimestamp": "2015-08-31T05:53:05.28",
"dataTypes": [
{
"count": 955,
"name": "Social Security Number"
},
{
"count": 555,
"name": "Credit Card Number"
},
"classifications": [
{
"count": 24,
"name": "Confidential"
},
{
"count": 12,
"name": "PII"
}
]
}]
}

Comment: [How to parse data in JSON format](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7771011) maybe?

Comment: the output is a string... i need to convert it first... hence my question

Comment: That's what `json.loads` does. See linked post. There's also `ast.literal_eval()`.

Comment: tried that... get error, updated post

Comment: Can you add some sample data? Hard to say what the issue is without seeing the data. You can also try jsonlint.com to validate the data.

Comment: i dont think its the data thats the issue, its being returned as a STR according to my print(type(resp2))

Comment: updated with data...

Comment: It's not valid JSON. The second `dataTypes` array is missing a closing `]`.

Comment: the data im working with is valid, according to online tools, i prefer to not use my actual data

Comment: I think i found the issue, everytime it returns data it is adding )]}', at the begining to prevent XSS is there a way to skip this?

Comment: I guess you could just skip the bad chars by finding the index of the first `{`. Ex: `data = json.loads(resp3[resp3.index('{'):])`