# How to pass kwargs from keyboard button to callback_query in aiogram?

Tags: python, callback, telegram, telegram-bot, aiogram

I am writing my first telegram bot and have encountered a strange problem. I cannot somehow pass kwargs from keyboard button to callback query, which should be executed after this button is clicked.

Here is the code:

```
async def handler(message: types.Message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    try:
        parser = Parser(message=message)
        for i in parser.parse():
            keyboard.add(InlineKeyboardButton(text=i[0],
                                              callback_data="answer",
                                              kwargs={"text": i[1][0],
                                                      "link": hlink(i[0], i[1][1])}))
        await message.answer("Here are the results:", reply_markup=keyboard)
    except (PageNotAccessible, TermNotFound, TooManyResults) as e:
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=user_id, text=str(e))


@dp.callback_query_handler(text=["answer"])
async def answer(call, text, link):
    await call.message.answer(f"{text}\n<i>{link}</i>")
```

But after clicking the button, it throws me this error:

```
TypeError: answer() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'text' and 'link'
```

So my question is how to pass kwargs to callback query in aiogram or how to do it any other way, without callbacks maybe?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to pass data is by using the `callback_data` param.

So to provide multiple values, the easiest way is to convert your data to JSON string, pass that, and on button click, decode the JSON

- [How can I parse (read) and use JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/how-can-i-parse-read-and-use-json)

---

Something like this (untested)

Pass an object with your data

```py
keyboard.add(
    InlineKeyboardButton(text=i[0],
        callback_data=json.dumps({
            "type": "answer", 
            "text": i[1][0],
            "link": hlink(i[0], i[1][1])})
    )
)
```

---

On the callback, decode the JSON

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text=["answer"])
async def answer(call, callback_data):
    decoded = json.loads(callback_data)
    # do something with the data from the json object
```

Comment: Now it throws me another error:                                                                                                  
```aiogram.utils.exceptions.ButtonDataInvalid: Button_data_invalid```                                 
As I understood, the reason for this is that callback_data shouldn`t be bigger than 64 bytes and my callback exceeds it.                                                                                                                                         Thanks for your advice anyway!

Comment: Ow yea, forgot to mention that. There is indeed a small limit. The best way is to create and save an uid in a db, then receive that on button press to check what kind of button it was.