# Extract key, value pair from nested json file

Tags: python, json

I am trying to extract the name, longitude and latitude from a json file and convert it into a new .csv file with the columns cityname | longitude | latitude

from this json: https://www.submarinecablemap.com/api/v3/landing-point/landing-point-geo.json

```
def cables():
    # print(page.text)
    # print(page2.text)
    # print(page3.text)

    json_file = 'exitpoints.json'

    with open(json_file) as json_data:
        data = json.load(json_data)

    # print(data)

    print("City: ", data['features.name'])
    #print("Longitude:  ", data['0'])
    #print("Latitude:  ", data['1'])
```

i tried all kinds of combinations data[features].data[name] etc...
how do i get this?

Comment: Have you tried `data['features']['name']`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I parse (read) and use JSON in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/how-can-i-parse-read-and-use-json-in-python) Look specifically at this comprehensive [answer by Karl Knechtel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/how-can-i-parse-read-and-use-json-in-python/75168292#75168292)

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to get the lat and long, you need to first iterate the `features` list and then unpack the `coordinates`

```
for i in data['features']:
    long = i['geometry']['coordinates'][0]
    lat = i['geometry']['coordinates'][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this, the traversal of the json is working like this, where you can get the name, longitude and latitude as well.

```
for feature in data['features']:
            name = feature['properties']['name']
            longitude, latitude = feature['geometry']['coordinates']
data = json.loads(json_data)
```

Full example

```
csv_file_path = "output.csv"

with open(csv_file_path, mode="w", newline='') as csv_file:
    fieldnames = ['name', 'longitude', 'latitude']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    
    # Write header
    writer.writeheader()

    # traverse data
    for feature in data['features']:
        name = feature['properties']['name']
        longitude, latitude = feature['geometry']['coordinates']
        writer.writerow({'name': name, 'longitude': longitude, 
        'latitude': latitude})
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this for example.

It assumes that you know that your data of interest in the 'features' list.

```py
import requests
import json

res = requests.get(r'https://www.submarinecablemap.com/api/v3/landing-point/landing-point-geo.json')
data = res.content()
data = json.loads(data)

csv_list = [f"{ele['properties']['name']};{';'.join(map(str, ele['geometry']['coordinates']))}" for ele in data['features']]
```

Now each row in `csv_list` contains the name, lon and lat as string. Delimiter is `;` since `,` is used in the name.

```
csv_list[0] 
>>> 'Changi South, Singapore;103.98701228871843;1.389044778364536'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `SimpleNamespace`

```py
from types import SimpleNamespace

import requests

url = "https://www.submarinecablemap.com/api/v3/landing-point/landing-point-geo.json"


def cables():
    response = requests.get(url)
    parsed = response.json(object_hook=lambda d: SimpleNamespace(**d))

    for f in parsed.features:
        print(f.properties.name, f.geometry.coordinates)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cables()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go friend, I've written the soluton in form of a script for you, but you can put it in a function too.

It helps that you pretify your JSON so you can understand the structure of it. There are several online prettifiers, but I often use this one: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

When you pretify the JSON you've provided it is instantly evident that all of the desired cities with the coordinates are in the `features` array.

Next you need to open a JSON file for reading and a CSV file for writing. Then you load the JSON like you already did, but you also prepare the csv dictionary writer and write a header to it.

JSON loads into an [associative array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array), so here `data` is the root, data['features'] is the list of all of the properties with geometry.

Then you go through each item in the `data['features']` and take what you need and write it into the CSV file. In the end you close the files, you don't have to, but it's a good practice.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import csv
import json

json_file = 'exitpoints.json'
csv_file = 'exitpoints.csv'

with open(json_file, 'r') as infile, open(csv_file, 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    data = json.load(infile)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, ['cityname', 'longitude', 'latitude'])
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in data['features']:
        cityname = row['properties']['name']
        longitude = row['geometry']['coordinates'][0]
        latitude = row['geometry']['coordinates'][1]
        
        writer.writerow({'cityname': cityname, 'longitude': longitude, 'latitude': latitude})

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

This script will create the CSV file named `exitpoints.csv` with the colums you've requested `cityname|longitude|latitude`.

To run it, don't forget to `chmod +x` make it executable if you are using a Unix based system.

Cheers!