# How can pass the parameter value form input.txt file using python?

Tags: python, python-requests, request

I want the pass the dynamic values in `params` from input.txt file?

**input.txt file:-**

```
term=ditech process solutions,country=IN,action=get_search_companies
```

**For this code:-**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def read_params(file_path):
    params = {}
    with open(file_path, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            key, value = line.strip().split('=')
            params[key] = value
    return params


api_url = "https://lei-registrations.in/wp/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"

input_file_path = "input.txt"

params = read_params(input_file_path)

# manual using params
# params = {
#     "term": "ditech process solutions",  # <-- search term
#     "country": "IN",
#     "action": "get_search_companies",
# }

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:122.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/122.0"
}

data = requests.get(api_url, params=params, headers=headers).json()

if data["success"]:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data["data"], "html.parser")
    for r in soup.select(".searchResults_title"):
        name = r.select_one(".searchResults_name").text
        number = r.select_one(".searchResults_number").text

        print(f"{name:<50} {number}")
```

Comment: If your input text file is comma separated (not via lines), you might want to consider using a CSV reader to iterate over such fields in a convenient way. Otherwise you should separate your input text file line-by-line.

Comment: @wLui155 Thanks for the reply, If I consider `csv` instead of `txt` file then how can we take can you give any example, and How can send the request according to the count's params?

Comment: Why not just use json in the text file? It can be parsed in to builtin python types and addressable using native python syntax...

Comment: @MatBailie, Thanks for the reply, I am new for python can please suggest any example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17493365/53341

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text file:

```
{
    "term": "ditech process solutions",
    "country": "IN",
    "action": "get_search_companies",
}
```

Code to read file:

```
import json

input_file_path = "input.txt"

with open(input_file_path) as json_data:
    params = json.load(json_data)
```

Documentation:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html