# How to search JSON for data, get vlaues from that array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, json

I have the below JSON. I want to search each array, and only scrape the data from the array which has keys and values in the "source" block, ignoring arrays which have an empty "source" block.
Here is the JSON:

```
{
    "L": [
        {
            "operation_no": 123456,
            "key1": "value1",
            "keys": {
                "no_seq": "1234",
                "external_key": null
            },
            "key2": 10234,
            "territory": {
                "territory_no": 1
            },
            "key3": "value",
            "source": []
        },
        {
            "operation_no": 123458,
            "key1": "value3",
            "keys": {
                "no_seq": "1237",
                "external_key": null
            },
            "key2": 10237,
            "territory": {
                "territory_no": 1
            },
            "key3": "value",
            "source": [
                {
                    "source1": "fhry4645fsgaa1",
                    "source2": "123egst36535a1"
                },
                {
                    "source1": "fhry4645fsgaa2",
                    "source2": "123egst36535a2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So, for example, the lower array which has "source" keys and values, I want to get the "operation_no" value (123458), but ignore the "operation_no" value thats has an empty "source" block (the first array).
How would I go about this using Python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I parse (read) and use JSON in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771011/how-can-i-parse-read-and-use-json-in-python)

Comment: If you don't want to do it by hand, it won't happen without code either. [ask]

Comment: This unfortunately does not answer my question.

Comment: Unfortunately SO expects you to make an honest attempt before asking. Again [ask]

Comment: You may find [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.12/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON data is presumably available as a string (perhaps from a file). Once you have the JSON as a string then:

```
import json

JSTR = '''{
    "L": [
        {
            "operation_no": 123456,
            "key1": "value1",
            "keys": {
                "no_seq": "1234",
                "external_key": null
            },
            "key2": 10234,
            "territory": {
                "territory_no": 1
            },
            "key3": "value",
            "source": []
        },
        {
            "operation_no": 123458,
            "key1": "value3",
            "keys": {
                "no_seq": "1237",
                "external_key": null
            },
            "key2": 10237,
            "territory": {
                "territory_no": 1
            },
            "key3": "value",
            "source": [
                {
                    "source1": "fhry4645fsgaa1",
                    "source2": "123egst36535a1"
                },
                {
                    "source1": "fhry4645fsgaa2",
                    "source2": "123egst36535a2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}'''

data = json.loads(JSTR)

for d in data.get("L", []):
    if d.get("source") and (operation_no := d.get("operation_no")):
        print(f"{operation_no=}")
```

**Output:**

```
operation_no=123458
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check for the length of "source", if it's not equal to 0, add it to a new list (here "usable_data) to work with it later. You can also add it to a new dictionary, of course.

```
my_dict = {
    "L": [
        {
            "operation_no": 123456,
            "key1": "value1",
            "keys": {
                "no_seq": "1234",
                "external_key": None
            },
            "key2": 10234,
            "territory": {
                "territory_no": 1
            },
            "key3": "value",
            "source": []
        },
        {
            "operation_no": 123458,
            "key1": "value3",
            "keys": {
                "no_seq": "1237",
                "external_key": None
            },
            "key2": 10237,
            "territory": {
                "territory_no": 1
            },
            "key3": "value",
            "source": [
                {
                    "source1": "fhry4645fsgaa1",
                    "source2": "123egst36535a1"
                },
                {
                    "source1": "fhry4645fsgaa2",
                    "source2": "123egst36535a2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

usable_data = []
for element in my_dict["L"]:
    if len(element["source"]) != 0:
        usable_data.append(element)
```

Comment: You seem to have modified the data in the OP to suit your code! Don't use built-in functions as variable names

Comment: @CtrlZ thanks for pointing that out, I will change the variable name! And yes, I assigned the JSON data to a variable name because I wouldn't know how to search the data without it being assigned to some kind of variable name at some point. Would that be even possible?

Comment: The source data will have to be accessible through some Python variable. However, you have changed the data (null -> None) with no explanation how you would achieve that programmatically. Data in the OP is almost certainly available as a string (probably from a file - but that's not clear)

Comment: @CtrlZ Again, true, I didn't explain it because it was not really scope of the question. I also think that the data will come in as string (including the "null", if it even exists because I am pretty sure most of these entrys are just random examples anyway) but as you said it's not clear where the data comes from. So I focused on answering how to find the elements within the data where "source" is not empty.