# Using two different data frames to compute new variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes of the same dimensions that look like:

```
   df1
ID    flag
0      1 
1      0
2      1

  df2
ID    flag
0      0 
1      1
2      0
```

In both dataframes I want to create a new variable that denotes an additive flag. So the new variable will look like this:

```
   df1
ID    flag   new_flag
0      1        1
1      0        1
2      1        1

  df2
ID    flag   new_flag
0      0        1
1      1        1
2      0        1
```

So if either flag columns is a `1` the new flag will be a `1`. 
I tried this code:

```
df1['new_flag']= 1
df2['new_flag']= 1

df1['new_flag'][(df1['flag']==0)&(df1['flag']==0)]=0
df2['new_flag'][(df2['flag']==0)&(df2['flag']==0)]=0
```

I would expect the same number of `1` in both `new_flag` but they differ. Is this because I'm not going row by row? Like this question? 
[pandas create new column based on values from other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886653/pandas-create-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns)
If so how do I include criteria from both datafrmes?

Comment: Also what you tried in principle should've worked but it's called chained indexing so you may have been operating on a copy which is why it didn't work, you should change to `df1.loc[(df1['flag']==0)&(df1['flag']==0), 'new_flag']=0
df2.loc[(df2['flag']==0)&(df2['flag']==0), 'new_flag']=0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.logical_or` to achieve this, if we set `df1` to be all 0's except for the last row so we don't just get a column of `1`'s, we can cast the result of `np.logical_or` using `astype(int)` to convert the boolean array to `1` and `0`:

```
In [108]:
df1['new_flag'] = np.logical_or(df1['flag'], df2['flag']).astype(int)
df2['new_flag'] = np.logical_or(df1['flag'], df2['flag']).astype(int)
df1

Out[108]:
   ID  flag  new_flag
0   0     0         0
1   1     0         1
2   2     1         1

In [109]:
df2

Out[109]:
   ID  flag  new_flag
0   0     0         0
1   1     1         1
2   2     0         1
```