# Create new column depending on other columns: DRY and go functional

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, functional-programming, currying

First: Maybe this fits better in code review, but I think here are more pandas affine users. Feel free to move it if you think otherwise

It is often the case, that one wants to compute a new column out of existing ones:
Consider the following pandas Dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ItemNumber':np.arange(1, 10), 
     'A':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3], 'B': [1,2,3]*3})
print(df)
   A  B  ItemNumber
0  1  1           1
1  1  2           2
2  1  3           3
3  2  1           4
4  2  2           5
5  2  3           6
6  3  1           7
7  3  2           8
8  3  3           9
```

Let's say we compute a new column 'C' via

```
df.loc[(df["A"] == 1) & (df["B"] > 1), 'C'] = 1
df.loc[(df["B"] == 1) & (df["A"] > 1), 'C'] = 2 
df.loc[(df["A"] > 1) &  (df["B"] > 1), 'C' ] = 3
df.loc[(df["A"] == 1) & (df["B"] == 1), 'C' ] = 4
```

This will perform quite fast also on large dataframes when compared to the iterative approach presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886653/pandas-create-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns).
Particularly, the perfomance issues with that approach lead me to the code presented above.

However, this code violates the DRY principle. Copy pasting feels akward.

So let's go a bit more functional and define two curried functions:

```
def col_equals_value(col, value):
    def filter_df(df):
        return df[col] == value
    return filter_df

def col_greater_value(col, value):
    def filter_df(df):
        return df[col] > value
    return filter_df
```

from there on, we define our comparisons:

```
a1 = col_equals_value('A', 1)
b1 = col_equals_value('B', 1)
agt1 = col_greater_value('A', 1)
bgt1 = col_greater_value('B', 1)
```

Another function is needed to assign the values to a column:

```
def assign_value(cond_1, cond_2, value):
    def assign_col_value(df, col):
        df.loc[df.apply(cond_1, axis=1) & df.apply(cond_2, axis=1), col] =value
    return assign_col_value
```

And finally, we can define the condtion-to-values mapping as

```
mapping = [(a1, b1, 4), 
           (a1, bgt1, 1), 
           (agt1, b1, 2), 
           (agt1, bgt1, 3)]
```

construct the assign_value_functions

```
m = [assign_value(x, y, z) for (x,y,z) in mapping]
```

and apply each function to the dataframe:

```
for f in m:
    f(df, 'C')
print(df)

   A  B  ItemNumber
0  1  1           1
1  1  2           2
2  1  3           3
3  2  1           4
4  2  2           5
5  2  3           6
6  3  1           7
7  3  2           8
8  3  3           9
```

So what are the questions?
This approach seems not very scalable. For each comparison operator I seem to need to define a completely new function. Can the comparison operator be a variable?
Currently, I'm only supporting 2 conditions concatenated with the & operator. How to generalize that?
I'm unsure about calling the apply method. I feel that there should be a simpler way.

Any help is welcome

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of `pandas.DataFrame.eval` here. First, define a dictionary `trans` which contains your transformations you want to apply. Second, employ a helper function `apply` which takes advantage of the eval:

```
trans = {"C": {"A == 1 and B > 1": 1,
               "B == 1 and A > 1": 2,
               "A > 1 and B > 1": 3,
               "A == 1 and B == 1": 4}}

def apply(sub_df, trans_dict):
    # sub_df = sub_df.copy() # in case you don't want change original df
    for column, transforms in trans_dict.items():
        for transform, value in transforms.items():
            sub_df.loc[sub_df.eval(transform), column] = value

    return sub_df

apply(df, trans)

    A   B   ItemNumber  C
0   1   1   1           4.0
1   1   2   2           1.0
2   1   3   3           1.0
3   2   1   4           2.0
4   2   2   5           3.0
5   2   3   6           3.0
6   3   1   7           2.0
7   3   2   8           3.0
8   3   3   9           3.0
```

I think it is justified to use pandas' *eval* here for greater readability. You can now supply whatever column-condition-value combinations to your `trans` dict.

However, we are still kind of violating DRY because every atomic condition like `A == 1` is evaluated multiple times instead of only once as in your provided example. But I guess there will be workarounds to efficiently memorize those boolean series.

Comment: hey, I really like your idea, it's straight forward, the mapping is defined relatively precisely. However, I'm not yet sure if I'm looking for a more functional solution. I think, my solution can be improved using the operator module and the reduce function to allow arbitrary many conditions. But the mapping/transformation might be less readable.