# How to use multiple columns from a df to run multiple conditions to calculate new column?

Tags: python, pandas

For example lets say I have a `df`

```
a    b     c       

1    3     5       
5    9     4
```

and I have `if`conditions:

```
if a < 2:
   3
elif  a < 3:
   4
else: b + c
```

How do I test the conditions and returns a result for each row of my df like below?

```
a    b     c    d

1    3     5    3 
5    9     4    13
```

edit: Ideally I want to create a `function` that allows me to

`def function(a, b, c)
df['d'] = function(a, b, c)`

and calculate for all rows of data. Because in the actual data, there is 100+ condition statements and 10s of columns.

Comment: check with np.select

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53505512/9209546) from possible duplicate [pandas create new column based on values from other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886653/pandas-create-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns).

Answer (score 1):

you can use apply method:

```
def custom_calc(x, a , b):
    if x[0] < 2:
        return 3

    if x[0] > 3:
        return x + a + b

df.a = df[['a', 'b', 'c']].apply(func=check, args=(df.b,df.c))
```

edit the custom function as you wish

Answer (score 1):

You could use `apply` function along axis 1.

```
def f(row):
    if row['a'] > 2:
        return 3
    elif row['a'] > 3:
        return 4
    else:
        return  row['b']+row['c']


df.apply(f,axis=1)

#output
0    8
1    3
dtype: int64
```