# Creating new Pandas column based on conditions, but the values do not generate

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to accomplish a simple task: creating a new column in a Pandas dataframe based on the conditions of other columns. I have consulted other posts (e.g., [this very popular one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886653/pandas-create-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns), but also others that took different approaches) but have been unsuccessful.

The problem I am having now is that only the *last* value defined in my function is returned in the new column

For example:

I have the following column:

```
x
1
2
3
```

I want to add a new column of labels thusly:

```
x     size
1     Small
2     Medium
3     Large
```

Here is the most recent attempt's code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('blah.csv')

def size (row):
    if row['rQ7'] == 1:
        return 'Small'
    if row['rQ7'] == 2:
        return 'Medium'
    if row['rQ7'] == 3:
        return 'Large'
    return -99 

'''
I have also tried breaking this into 
else: 
    return -99 
but it doesn't work. '''

df['size'] = df.apply (lambda row: size (row), axis=1)
```

Now, while I do not get any errors, when I apply the function to the dataframe, it only returns the last value, i.e., -99:

```
x    size
1    -99
2    -99
3    -99
```

This is also true for other functions I have tried, and when I tried to use `df.loc[]`, Python would not copy *any* of the values to the new column, although no errors were present.

I am confused and at a loss: to me, and based on the other examples I have tried, it appears the code *should* work.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.select()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
df['col']=np.select([df.x.eq(1),df.x.eq(2),df.x.eq(3)],['small','medium','large'],\
                                                                  'something')
```

you can replace `'something'` with the value which should appear when the conditions are not met.

```
print(df)

   x    size
0  1   small
1  2  medium
2  3   large
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I am still having the issue where only 'something' is returned. All the other conditions are ignored. I am using Spyder to program, but I tried it in a different editor and was able to replicate the problem.

Comment: @n0ro shouldnot be the case if you have correctly demonstrated the issue in the question. check for datatypes etc.. :)

Comment: The numbers were being treated as strings for some reason by Spyder! Thanks so much for the obvious solution! It works now xD

Comment: @n0ro no problem. :) Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try more simple version:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('blah.csv')

def size(x):
    if x == 1:
        return 'Small'
    if x == 2:
        return 'Medium'
    if x == 3:
        return 'Large'
    return -99 

# maybe your row type is"string"
df['size'] = df['rQ7'].apply (lambda x: size(int(x)))
```