# Speed up Pandas: find all columns which fullfill set of conditions

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I have data represented using pandas DataFrame, which for example looks as follows:

```
| id | entity | name | value | location
```

where `id` is an `integer` value, `entity` is an `integer` , `name` is a `string`, `value` is an `integer`, and `location` is a `string` (for example US, CA, UK etc).

Now, I want to add a new column to this data frame, column "`flag`", where values are assigned as follows:

```
for d in df.iterrows():

    if d.entity == 10 and d.value != 1000 and d.location == CA:
        d.flag = "A" 
    elif d.entity != 10 and d.entity != 0 and d.value == 1000 and d.location == US:
        d.flag = "C"
    elif d.entity == 0 and d.value == 1000 and d.location == US"
        d.flag = "B"
    else:
        print("Different case")
```

Is there a way to speed this up and use some built in functions instead of the for loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`np.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) which you pass a list of conditions, based on those conditions you give it choices and you can specify a default value when none of the conditions is met.

```
conditions = [
    (d.entity == 10) & (d.value != 1000) & (d.location == 'CA'),
    (d.entity != 10) & (d.entity != 0) & (d.value == 1000) & (d.location == 'US'),
    (d.entity == 0) & (d.value == 1000) & (d.location == 'US')
]

choices = ["A", "C", "B"]

df['flag'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default="Different case")
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks interesting! One question - should I do it per row (since d is a single row), so still in a loop?

Comment: No, this is a vectorized solution. Loops in python general and pandas are slow. So use the last line to create your new column called `flag`. @Ziva

Answer (score 4):

Add `()` with bitwise `and` -> `&` for working with [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
m = [
    (d.entity == 10) & (d.value != 1000) & (d.location == 'CA'),
    (d.entity != 10) & (d.entity != 0) & (d.value == 1000) & (d.location == 'US'),
    (d.entity == 0) & (d.value == 1000) & (d.location == 'US')
]

df['flag'] = np.select(m, ["A", "C", "B"], default="Different case")
```

Answer (score 0):

You wrote "find all columns which fulfill a set of conditions", but your code shows you're actually trying to add a new column whose value for each row is computed from the values of other columns of the same row.

If that's indeed the case, you can use [`df.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html), giving it a function that computes the value for a specific row:

```py
def flag_value(row):
    if row.entity == 10 and row.value != 1000 and row.location == CA:
        return "A"
    elif row.entity != 10 and row.entity != 0 and row.value == 1000 and row.location == US:
        return "C"
    elif row.entity == 0 and row.value == 1000 and row.location == US:
        return "B"
    else:
        return "Different case"

df['flag'] = df.apply(flag_value, axis=1)
```

Take a look at [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886653/pandas-create-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns) for more information.

If you truly want to *find all columns which specify some condition*, the usual way to do this with a Pandas dataframe is to use `df.loc` and indexing:

```py
only_a_cases = df.loc[df.entity == 10 & df.value != 1000 & df.location == "CA"]
# or:
only_a_cases = df.loc[lambda df: df.entity == 10 & df.value != 1000 & df.location == "CA"]
```