# try to assign value to new column based on non blank entry of other column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-2.7

I need to assign "correct" to a new column"A" based on other column"B" condition , that is:- if  column "B" has non blank entry then column "A" will assign value of "Correct" else "check required"
condition we have:
 if column "B" contains any non blank entry then column "A" will assign with "correct"
input:-
Name    B   A
Adam    34
Screen
binny   35
tough
sunny   5
petter

output:-
    Name    B   A
0   Adam    34.0    Correct
1   Screen      Correct
2   binny   35.0    Correct
3   tough       Correct
4   sunny   5.0 Correct
5   petter      Correct

I have tried the following:

```
df.loc[df['A'] != '', 'B'] = "Correct"
```

input [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeZS9.png)

output [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXeoZ.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas create new column based on values from other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886653/pandas-create-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns)

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886653/pandas-create-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns

Comment: i seen that example before,it is some different what i am facing actually , i have to apply condition when exiting column not equal to blank, means if exiting column contains any value then , new column will assign with "correct".

Comment: provide sample data and expected output in your question

Comment: I guess you need `df.loc[df['A'].notna(), 'B'] = "Correct"` - if empty value is missing value

Answer (score 0):

```
def label_A(row):
  if row['B'].notna():
    return "Correct"
  else:
    return "Check Required"
```

`df['A'] = df.apply(lambda row: label_A(row), axis=1)`

This is based on the answer given in: [pandas create new column based on values from other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886653/pandas-create-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns)

The function label_A() checks if the value of column B is empty or no and then assigns the appropriate value to column A.

Comment: i tried it... but actually it assigning "Correct" for blank entry as well non blank entries..i am sharing input details & output details

Comment: I edited it slightly. Try the notna() instead of != ''

Comment: Not working... with above code.. finally this code working for correct condition
df.loc[df['B'].notna(), 'A'] = "Correct"

Answer (score 0):

finally this code working
df.loc[df['B'].notna(), 'A'] = "Correct"