# Question on how to create a new column based on current df columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to figure out how to create a new column for my df and cant seem to get it to work with what I have tried.

I have tried using

```py
loans_df.insert("Debt_Ratio",["MonthlyDebt"*12/"Income"])
```

but I keep getting an error stating unsupported operand type.

BTW I am calculating the new column using already predefined columns in my df

```py
loans_df.insert("Debt_Ratio",["MonthlyDebt"*12/"Income"])
```

My expected results would be that this new column is inserted into the df with the specific calculation defining it.

Hope this all makes sense!

Comment: IIUC, you need df["Debt_Ratio"] = df["MonthlyDebt"] * 12/df["Income"]

Comment: Thank you, I figured it was something I was missing in regards to using insert instead of making the parameters equal the new column. Is there anyway I can mark this as solved? Can't see anywhere on here for the acceptance of the answer

Comment: It’s a duplicate so only two options; either you delete the question or I write a solution as an answer:)

Comment: Oh no did I ask a question that was already asked ?! If so I will delete the question once I get home from work :o

Comment: Yup, not an exact duplicate but there are many variations of this on SO already. That’s the reason i answered as a comment

Comment: Well great..I didn't want to be that guy. I will make sure to take it down after I get home

Comment: Possible duplicate of [pandas create new column based on values from other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886653/pandas-create-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns)

Answer (score 0):

Considering that dataframe is `loans_df` and that the column you want to create is named `Debt_Ratio`, the following will do the work

```
loans_df['Debt_Ratio'] = loans_df['MonthlyDebt'] * 12/loans_df['Income']
```