# How to use dataframe column in for loop

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I am trying to implement a formula to create a new column in Dataframe using existing column but that column is a summation from 0 to a number present in some other column.

I was trying something like this:

```
dataset['B']=sum([1/i for i in range(dataset['A'])])
```

I know something like this would work
dataset['B']=sum([1/i for i in range(10)])

but I want to make this 10 dynamic based on some different column.

I keep on getting this error.

TypeError: 'Series' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all, I should admit that I could not understand you question completely. However, what I understood that you want to iterate over the rows of a DataFrame and make a new column by doing some operation/s on that value.
   Is that is so, then I would recommend you [following link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886653/pandas-create-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns)
2. Regarding `TypeError: 'Series' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`:
   The init signature `range()` takes integers as input. i.e `[i for i in range(10)]` should give you `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`. However, if one of the `value` from your `dataset['A']` is float, or not integer , this might result in the error you are having. Moreover, if you notice, the first value is a zero, as a result, `1/i` should result in a different error. As a result, you might have to rewrite the code as [1/i for i in range (1 , row_value_of_dataset['A'])]

It will be highly appreciate if you could make an example of what you DataFrame might look like and what is your desired output. Then perhaps it is easier to post a solution.

*BTW forgot to post what I understood from your question:*

```py
#assume the data:
>>>import pandas as pd
>>>data = pd.DataFrame({'A': (1, 2, 3, 4)})
#the data
>>>data
  A
0  1
1  2
2  3
3  4
#doing operation on each of the rows
>>>data['B']=data.apply(lambda row: sum([1/i for i  in range(1, row.A)] ), axis=1)
# Column B is the newly added data
>>>data
   A         B
0  1  0.000000
1  2  1.000000
2  3  1.500000
3  4  1.833333
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution.This method is too slow as I am working on very big data. Can you please suggest some optimized way.

Comment: use numba in numpy and then bring it into the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps explicitly use `cumsum`, or even `apply`?

Anyway trying to move an array/list item directly into a dataframe and seem to view this as a dictionary. Try something like this, I've not tested it,

```
array_x = [x, 1/x for x in dataset.values.tolist()] # or `dataset.A.tolist()`
df = pd.DataFrame(data=(np.asarray(array_x)))
df.columns = [A, B]
```

Here the idea is to break the Series apart into a list, and input the list into a  dataframe. This can be explicitly done without needing to go `Series->list->dataframe` and is not very efficient.