# 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'withColumn'

Tags: python, pyspark

I am trying to compare two pandas dataframes but I get an error as  'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'withColumn'. What could be the issue?

```
import pandas as pd
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

pd_df=pd.DataFrame(df.dtypes,columns=['column','data_type'])
pd_df1=pd.DataFrame(df1.dtypes,columns=['column','data_type'])

pd.merge(pd_df,pd_df1, on='column', how='outer'
    ).withColumn(
    "result",
    F.when(F.col("data_type_x") == 'NaN','new attribute'.otherwise('old attribute')))
    .select(
    "column",
    "data_type_x",
    "data_type_y",
    "result"
    )
```

df and df1 are some data frames

Comment: Input dataframe has. If you say `write()`, input is already lost.

Answer (score 4):

You mixed up pandas dataframe and Spark dataframe.

The issue is pandas `df` doesn't have spark function `withColumn`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Thanks for the help.

```
def res(df):
    if df['data_type_x'] == df['data_type_y']:
        return 'no change'
    elif pd.isnull(df['data_type_x']):
        return 'new attribute'
    elif pd.isnull(df['data_type_y']):
        return 'deleted attribute'
    elif df['data_type_x'] != df['data_type_y'] and not pd.isnull(df['data_type_x']) and not pd.isnull(df['data_type_y']):
        return 'datatype change'

pd_merge['result'] = pd_merge.apply(res, axis = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are setting these up as Pandas DataFrames and not Spark DataFrames. For joins with Pandas DataFrames, you would want to use

```
DataFrame_output = DataFrame.join(other, on=None, how='left', lsuffix='', rsuffix='', sort=False)
```

Run this to understand what DataFrame it is.

```
type(df)
```

To use `withColumn`, you would need Spark DataFrames. If you want to convert the DataFrames, use this:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas as pd

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('pandasToSparkDF').getOrCreate()
df = spark.createDataFrame(pd_df1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible to add a new column (with above logic) to Pandas Dataframe without converting to Spark DataFrame?

Comment: Yes, I would look at this 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886653/pandas-create-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns