# How can I abstract a value from another column with a condition?

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I want to create a column, based on values in another column. I found this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886653/pandas-create-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns), but I don't think that this is going to work, since I need to check all the 'Unique_String' values, before 'abstracting' the data.

**What do I want?**

I want to 'loop'(?) through my 'Text' column, see if there is data available. If not, it should look into the 'Unique_String' column, and abstract (if available) the values, and paste it into the Text column.

**Data**

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Unique_String                 Text 
AAA                           Here is text! 
AAA                           nan
BBB                           nan
BBB                           Here is text as well! 
BBB                           Feyenoord
CCC                           nan
CCC                           nan
```

**The desired output is:**

```
Unique_String                 Text 
AAA                           Here is text! 
AAA                           Here is text!
BBB                           Here is text as well!
BBB                           Here is text as well! 
BBB                           Feyenoord
CCC                           nan
CCC                           nan
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: `df.groupby('Unique_String')['Text'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is necessary call functions forward and back filling per groups:

```
df['Text'] = df.groupby('Unique_String')['Text'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
print (df)
  Unique_String                   Text
0           AAA          Here is text!
1           AAA          Here is text!
2           BBB  Here is text as well!
3           BBB  Here is text as well!
4           BBB              Feyenoord
5           CCC                    NaN
6           CCC                    NaN
```