# How can I evaluate the last number in a dictionary and replace the number with text?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

I was fiddling around with a few different algos to do text sentiment analysis.  So far, all were squirley, except for one.  This one looks like it's pretty accurate.

```
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()
df['sentiment'] = df['review_text'].apply(lambda x: sid.polarity_scores(x))
```

That gives me dictionary results, like this:

```
{'neg': 0.315, 'neu': 0.593, 'pos': 0.093, 'compound': -0.7178}
{'neg': 0.215, 'neu': 0.556, 'pos': 0.229, 'compound': 0.0516}
{'neg': 0.373, 'neu': 0.133, 'pos': 0.493, 'compound': 0.2263}
{'neg': 0.242, 'neu': 0.547, 'pos': 0.211, 'compound': -0.1027}
{'neg': 0.31, 'neu': 0.69, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': -0.6597}
```

I'm trying to figure out how to evaluate the last number in each row (-0.7178, 0.0516, 0.2263, -0.1027, -0.6597) and apply the following logic:

```
If compound <= 0 Then negative
ElseIf compound > .2 Then positive
Else neutral
```

I tried to find a substring within the dictionary, like this:

```
sub = '''compound':'''
df['Indexes'] = df['sentiment'].str.find(sub)  
df
```

I was thinking of finding the position, and then get the last number, and then run the logic I described above.  I starting to think that's not the right approach.  What's the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: do you get string or dictionary `{'neg': 0.315, 'neu': 0.593, 'pos': 0.093, 'compound': -0.7178}` ? Maybe you need `apply(lambda x: if x['compound'] < = 0 : ...)`

Comment: Sorry, it's a dictionary.  I'll update my question.

Comment: If you have dictionary then maybe you need `df['sentiment'].apply(lambda x: if x['compound'] < = 0 : ...)`

Comment: You get a Series of dictionaries? In that case you can use `.map()` or `.apply()`, right? _I tried to find a substring within the dictionary, like this:_ https://realpython.com/python-dicts/

Comment: Do you mean it should be like this?

df['sentiment_label'] = df['sentiment'].apply(lambda x: if x['compound'] <= 0 : 'negative')

That's giving me: SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: it is not complet - it needs also `else` which may need another `if/else`

Comment: Is this not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886653/pandas-create-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns-apply-a-function-o?rq=1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply()` which gets `x['compound']` and convert to `"negative"`, `"positive"` or `"neutral"`

```
def convert(x):
    if x <= 0:
        return "negative"
    elif x > .2:
        return "positive"
    else:
        return "neutral"

df['result'] = df['sentiment'].apply(lambda x:convert(x['compound']))
```

---

Minimal working code

```
import nltk
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
import pandas as pd

def convert(x):
    if x <= 0:
        return "negative"
    elif x > .2:
        return "positive"
    else:
        return "neutral"

sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'review_text': ['bad', 'ok', 'fun', 'neutral']
})

df['sentiment'] = df['review_text'].apply(lambda x: sid.polarity_scores(x))

df['result'] = df['sentiment'].apply(lambda x:convert(x['compound']))

print(df[['review_text', 'result']])
```

Result

```
  review_text    result
0         bad  negative
1          ok  positive
2         fun  positive
3     neutral  negative
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
# data = df['sentiment'] I just abstracted it to data so it looks better.

data = [
{'neg': 0.315, 'neu': 0.593, 'pos': 0.093, 'compound': -0.7178},
{'neg': 0.215, 'neu': 0.556, 'pos': 0.229, 'compound': 0.0516},
{'neg': 0.373, 'neu': 0.133, 'pos': 0.493, 'compound': 0.2263},
{'neg': 0.242, 'neu': 0.547, 'pos': 0.211, 'compound': -0.1027},
{'neg': 0.31, 'neu': 0.69, 'pos': 0.0, 'compound': -0.6597}
]

def evaluate(num):
  if(num < 0):
    return 'negative'
  elif (num > 0.2):
    return 'positive'
  else:
    return "neutral"


for item in data:
  num = item['compound'];
  print(num, ' is', evaluate(num));
```

output:

```
-0.7178  is negative
0.0516  is neutral
0.2263  is positive
-0.1027  is negative
-0.6597  is negative
```

Comment: Your example works, aviya, but how can I apply this over a field in a dataframe?  That's where I am stuck.  It seems like you have a list.  I have a dictionary within a field in a dataframe; df['sentiment'].  I can replace this field, or add a new field next to this one.  It doesn't matter.  I want to do whatever is easier.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's looks like dict(), not str.
If its dict you can take your compound use this:

```
df['sentiment']['compound']
```

If its str you can split your str, and take last part.
Example:

```
df['Indexes'] = float(df['sentiment'].str.split('compound: ')[1])
```