# Efficient way to conditionally modify columns in a pandas dataframe, row by row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
length      code1    code2    code3
4            0         1        1
8            1         1        0
7            1         0        0
```

I want to write a function that checks the value in length. If the value is >= 7, I want to add 1 to the value present in code2 and code3. What is the best way to do this? So far, I have:

```
def char_count_pred(df):
    
    
    if df.length >= 7:
           df.code2 += 1
           df.code3 += 1

    return df


master_df = char_count_pred(master_df)
```

I understand I need to build a loop to iterate over each row, but I am confused on the most efficient way to loop through rows of and performing tasks on multiple columns.

#### edit

When trying the solutions below, I get the same errors:

When I try the  script as is....

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2889             try:
-> 2890                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2891             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type()

KeyError: True
```

When I set the script to = a variable...

```
  File "<ipython-input-140-9f2f40a5bb96>", line 3
    df = df.loc[df.length>=7]+=1
                                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help:

**EDIT**
This is everything, which i am using:
Definition of your datafrme:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["length","code1","code2","code3"],
                  data=[[4,0,1,1],
                        [8,1,1,0],
                        [7,1,0,0]])
```

Definition of the function:

```
def char_count_pred(df):
    for col in df.columns:
        df[col].loc[df[col]>7]+=1
char_count_pred(df)
```

Everything works, I don't know, where the problem is.

Comment: This solution throws the errors listed above, any ideas?

Comment: got it working. FYI on line 3 of your function, the section [col] needs to be ['length']. Thanks! Accepting your solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
df.loc[df.length >=7, ['code1','code2']]+=1
```

Comment: This solution throws the errors listed above, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

```
df.loc[df['length']>=7, 'code2':] += 1
```

Use .loc to search for rows greater than or equal to 7, then select the correct columns and add 1

Answer (score 0):

You could perform an `apply` which would likely be close to the most efficient way of modifying your columns based on some function.

There's an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886653/pandas-create-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns-apply-a-function-o) you could take a look at, or - try something like this as a template for your specific use-case:

```
master_df["code2"] = master_df.apply(lambda x : x["code2"] + 1 if x["length"] >= 7 else x["code2"], axis=1)
```

Which will update your "code2" field by applying a function (in this case an anonymous `lamba` function, but could equally be some named function as per your def) the only limitation being that it's simpler if those functions target a single column at a time.

There are methods for updating/generating results to update multiple columns at once, but it might be simpler to start of updating single columns at a time.