# numpy select TypeError: unhashable type: 'list - numpy requires list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to use the value of one column in a dataframe to generate a new column as seen in this stackoverflow post:[pandas create new column based on values from other columns / apply a function of multiple columns, row-wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886653/pandas-create-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns-apply-a-function-o)

When I try to run the following code:

```
conditions = [
    newData['month'] == 1,
    newData['month'] == 2,
    newData['month'] == 3,
    newData['month'] == 4,
    newData['month'] == 5,
    newData['month'] == 6,
    newData['month'] == 7,
    newData['month'] == 8,
    newData['month'] == 9,
    newData['month'] == 10,
    newData['month'] == 11,
    newData['month'] == 12]
output = [1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4]
newData['quarter'] = newData.select(conditions, output)
```

I get the error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

I understand that lists aren't hashable, but numpy requires lists for both arguments.

From the documentation:

> condlist : list of bool ndarrays The list of conditions which determine from which array in choicelist the output elements are taken. When multiple conditions are satisfied, the first one encountered in condlist is used.
>
> condlist : list of bool ndarrays The list of conditions which determine from which array in choicelist the output elements are taken. When multiple conditions are satisfied, the first one encountered in condlist is used.

I can't figure out what the issue is

Comment: Ah, I knew it was going to be something basic I was missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
newData['quarter'] = (newData['month'].sub(1) // 3).add(1)
```

if there are no repeated months and they are ordered:

```
newData['quarter'] =  newData['month'].mod(3).eq(1).cumsum().add(1)
```

Your problem is that you wanted `np.select`

```
import numpy as np
newData['quarter'] = np.select(conditions, output)
```