# How to calculate age from a Dataframe column DOB(object type) and populate age in a new column Age using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a data frame customer:

```
Name   DOB         Age?
A     12/10/1953
B     16/12/1980
C     20/01/1954
D     03/10/1961
E     13/05/1977
```

After calculating age I want to populate it in the Age column.
Can anyone help in doing this?

Comment: Do you want to use today's date to calculate Age?

Comment: @kait yes, I want to calculate age using today's date

Comment: Does this answer you question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/26886653/13552470

Answer (score 4):

Coerce `DOB` to `datetime` and subtract from today's date if you wanted current age in years.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
df['Age?']=(dt.datetime.today()\
            -pd.to_datetime(df['DOB'])).astype('timedelta64[Y]')

Name         DOB  Age?
0    A  12/10/1953  66.0
1    B  16/12/1980  39.0
2    C  20/01/1954  66.0
3    D  03/10/1961  59.0
4    E  13/05/1977  43.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your help

Comment: Happy I was of help. Nice week ahead

Comment: Note that this answer does not work with pandas 2