# How to create virtual columns / expression columns in pandas dataframes?

Tags: pandas

I am looking for script which will print `salary`, `annualsalary`, `bonus` of an employee. `sal` is the only column available in DF, and other two columns are expressions which will derive from `sal`.

```
annualsalary = 12*sal, bonus=sal*comm/100
```

i am trying below code

```
empdf.loc[:,'sal':][['sal'], ['sal']*12, ['sal']*['comm']/100]
```

can you help me in correcting above code?

Comment: where does `comm` come from if it's not a column?  Is it a constant?

Comment: Please [add](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/7403431) a portion of your df. You also didn't mentioned that `comm` is in your df.

Comment: Do you want this? `print(empdf.sal, empdf.sal * 12, (empdf.sal * comm) / 100)`

Comment: Please review this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886653/pandas-create-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns-apply-a-function-o

Comment: my DF has columns EMPNO, NAME, SAL, COMM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use temporary calculated fields with `assign()`

```
import random
df = pd.DataFrame([{"sal":random.randint(10,15)*100} for i in range(10)])
comm = 20
df.assign(
    annualsalary=lambda dfa: dfa["sal"]*12,
    bonus=lambda dfa: dfa["sal"]*(comm/100)
)
```

**output**

```
  sal  annualsalary  bonus
 1000         12000  200.0
 1400         16800  280.0
 1200         14400  240.0
 1400         16800  280.0
 1500         18000  300.0
 1500         18000  300.0
 1100         13200  220.0
 1300         15600  260.0
 1000         12000  200.0
 1000         12000  200.0
```

Comment: using `lambda` is redundant here, you can just do `df.assign(annualsalary = df['sal']*12, bonus = df['sal']*(comm/100))`

Comment: @Ch3steR agreed - however for future maintainability where columns are derived off derived columns,  I use pattern of always use `lambda`