# Pandas Dataframe replace string based on length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a pandas dataframe (df2) with about 160,000 rows. I'm trying to change some of the values in a column (url).

The strings in this column have lengths between 108 and 150 characters. If the string is not 108 characters, I want to replace it with the same string, cutting off the last 10 characters. IF the string is 108 characters. I want to leave it alone. Please note that i'm not trying to make every string 108 characters, I'm just trying to cut off the last 10 characters of any string that isn't 108 characters.

example: len(s) = 114, replace with s[:-10]

I built a function that will do this, but it's insanely slow, probably because it rebuilds the dataframe in each loop.

```
for i in df2.url:
    if len(i) != 108:
        new_i = i[:-10]
        df2 = df2.replace(i,new_i)
```

There has to be a faster way to do this, but I haven't been able to figure out how. I would love the expertise of someone more versed in pandas.

Below is an example of 200 rows of the column I'm trying to change:

```
['https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1301108?gameHash=bde58669fc59c853&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1291187?gameHash=f7fcd2d6ca775fb5&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1291192?gameHash=005335984c8f8a3a&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1301128?gameHash=fcbd2630c0faec49&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1301159?gameHash=9a7726176fdabfde&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1301169?gameHash=5d816e6d30d2b659&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1301183?gameHash=396641afdcdd99d9&amp;tab=overview',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT02/1271494?gameHash=bd51798e1358c47f',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130153?gameHash=00a7861ac0a23aef',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT02/1271495?gameHash=0d828bbc9aa9996c',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT02/1271497?gameHash=bd4810bb801abf24',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130166?gameHash=1cff679b64acb047',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130177?gameHash=1f92cbefd9a965e0',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT02/1271500?gameHash=abbdae6c3e7b4006',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT02/1271505?gameHash=7c970a84e132a578',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130182?gameHash=ccb50f6e86e4c3df',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130193?gameHash=0995997660a65721',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1301262?gameHash=c594a9a52f46cc50',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130196?gameHash=31553f5bb6ba4420',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1301270?gameHash=5b3babb5d392d78d',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130201?gameHash=3d2aa031c17d90ae',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1301290?gameHash=31ce80069fdbc873',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130210?gameHash=91c7b22cded939ff',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1301305?gameHash=3f8d664b3b988446',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130221?gameHash=a8580ee66ffbb525',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1291406?gameHash=5220923eb35c42c6',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1291426?gameHash=83c7c51530ea074e',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1291442?gameHash=28f7b485f710168f',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1291458?gameHash=49cc14d02ccd0674',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1291470?gameHash=f087c853097c2dd9',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT02/1261474?gameHash=e6c01a288de5dc41',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130229?gameHash=1489421028163983',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT02/1261475?gameHash=c984e795d6406cd5',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130243?gameHash=5491d110de253089',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT02/1261482?gameHash=f2283324f82caa66&amp;tab=overview',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130253?gameHash=f8e39ae785d11c0c',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130264?gameHash=a98718c088ce663c',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT02/1261488?gameHash=6517011920487fbf&amp;tab=overview',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1291651?gameHash=5ec1b3473060dfd2',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1291682?gameHash=a8f2c06d04117279',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1291703?gameHash=cfb2d078f289825c',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1291737?gameHash=cf67a15df43c2bb2',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1291748?gameHash=7a3c085cf703d7bd',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1291789?gameHash=51e5ed28085fd299',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1291812?gameHash=e540d208bbc69bb3',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1291835?gameHash=a75ab48a22470022',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1291845?gameHash=2eab12f8ffd0dfd0',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130294?gameHash=ecf040ad60fa9726&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130299?gameHash=499a21480080a722&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130306?gameHash=d0e60bf49b6bf008&amp;tab=overview',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1292296?gameHash=3db885bd11a047bc',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1292315?gameHash=2ecf71aaea031312',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1292329?gameHash=5ed85b948b32b8e8',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1292341?gameHash=7335d6ca06763dc0&amp;tab=overview',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1292345?gameHash=6f86444cce429244',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1292348?gameHash=c6a4eec48810e8d5&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1292353?gameHash=6db57c090ed235bd&amp;tab=overview',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1292354?gameHash=79845cdf9a6e88db',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1120429?gameHash=436739b9e99a246e&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1120436?gameHash=58bc4281a76534f3&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1120440?gameHash=4b74592ff226c39f&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1120447?gameHash=9358d210749ab778&amp;tab=overview',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1292579?gameHash=14865e88bd1e30a7',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1292607?gameHash=0ae34d7f67620dc4',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1292635?gameHash=f94944bb4f061f0d',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1292648?gameHash=1338dde99c71877f&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1302501?gameHash=f71748ae9cad5866&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1302519?gameHash=672c1377c3d37ed0&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1302531?gameHash=49cf9a8f3942b9c8&amp;tab=overview',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1302595?gameHash=314d39ea940b354f',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1302628?gameHash=0ab39ec364a3ff5b',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1302635?gameHash=5625553825f5994e',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1302651?gameHash=555c7cd73dff952d',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1292960?gameHash=e3ce73c142354517',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1292974?gameHash=ab79b8f6f354bc0b',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1302827?gameHash=6a1a5de57a7ce6b9&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1302855?gameHash=f9144d0822d68632&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1302881?gameHash=369cd071defeadd9&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1302906?gameHash=c65d2e76e9aa721e&amp;tab=overview',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130488?gameHash=411522a3de69bb79',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130489?gameHash=51c4c81c13a484c7',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130496?gameHash=9575986535e4f4c2',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1293312?gameHash=8e2209227e28843b',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1120557?gameHash=f5bec07774ed5a5e',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1293319?gameHash=762cb3a92744846f',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130515?gameHash=548d7e528ef1f81e',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1293370?gameHash=8a70038d2eba61de',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1293393?gameHash=841d85edbfa78057',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130518?gameHash=6764d64a5ef8377e&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1120578?gameHash=838a1db0f44411c8&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1120583?gameHash=c542c3368048efd6&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1120585?gameHash=925d9c523a0b0bdb&amp;tab=overview',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1293765?gameHash=53412e36eb2eab86',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1303478?gameHash=8df5ef3d826ad211&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1303509?gameHash=d0849b1ba82d4826&amp;tab=overview',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1293812?gameHash=48d825f1bb110b55',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1303533?gameHash=3a712b015a672d8d&amp;tab=overview',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1293850?gameHash=0a29fdee10ed35d0',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1293885?gameHash=1ffaffd98da7e806',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1303581?gameHash=2bf61273d44c302f&amp;tab=overview',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1293897?gameHash=77ccf507e1eaa05c',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1293899?gameHash=aa93723cded96f3b',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1293901?gameHash=f5fb660360f96ad6',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1293909?gameHash=245dbdf428788434',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1303619?gameHash=2e2f2ff9c6a32595&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1303626?gameHash=3bba86d0f9ff1d11&amp;tab=overview',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1293929?gameHash=f4b6f53e68bbbc86',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1303641?gameHash=25ffa91aeb9ed707',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1293950?gameHash=e2f3a99412844d36',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1303655?gameHash=4ff2ebbe72e635bb',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1293964?gameHash=10bd6ec239231196',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130548?gameHash=afd267703d3cbbb1&amp;tab=overview',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1303666?gameHash=a30e98d241d22eef',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130553?gameHash=f4360fb632593491&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130560?gameHash=e1e5bae936585a24&amp;tab=overview',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1120607?gameHash=f4b702f689f87c90',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130563?gameHash=43a7c73ecd281a63&amp;tab=overview',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1120622?gameHash=c87f08d06f392f3f',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1120629?gameHash=6b39ee929c2ebc47',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1120638?gameHash=eb17c2013b9ee77d',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1120649?gameHash=aab6f321110ef3ed',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1294174?gameHash=8f5cb3f02bf790d7&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1303861?gameHash=02847551947ca67d&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1294191?gameHash=e574ac58bbe81abb&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1303876?gameHash=e733bc45e47f4856&amp;tab=overview',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1303904?gameHash=d8aac7332b9edfe8',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1294233?gameHash=6762c2c72bc47359&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1303974?gameHash=28f566b2fa35a32a&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1294260?gameHash=246841d34c9660aa&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1303999?gameHash=619d5a2d571a1b01&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304020?gameHash=99508a2da285eb4c&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304032?gameHash=30e5b243a407326c&amp;tab=overview',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304035?gameHash=f8e3702e77f87cc7',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304054?gameHash=db39c4bcb7c2320e&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304075?gameHash=a3d0d6acfb8b92f1&amp;tab=overview',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304079?gameHash=8339c23d8d925f8b',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304081?gameHash=d3e5c8f0270ce96f&amp;tab=overview',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304111?gameHash=64ded61e41c18ccd',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304122?gameHash=bf7e80351592ce98',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304132?gameHash=ff37582431bd7e7b&amp;tab=overview',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130611?gameHash=a099e1df984018a1',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304158?gameHash=62b9c13c8cecf652',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1294417?gameHash=746905a629b8f374',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130621?gameHash=9d171c9622870a7b',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304165?gameHash=c34ae80c4ee8c7bd',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304169?gameHash=ee6bc6a087a6bc36&amp;tab=overview',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304193?gameHash=fe234e8ca7d2343f',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130630?gameHash=b1b183ad3374db06',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304217?gameHash=b29c2b7461c7700f',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304223?gameHash=7c70a52e69b01c56',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130643?gameHash=15bb88ac79a622a1&amp;tab=overview',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1120705?gameHash=a6532b3af6accaf2',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304264?gameHash=f5e69d8e2f6bae5e',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1120711?gameHash=79659ad2d107f0d9',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304282?gameHash=f9ea42cec97e930f',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130676?gameHash=f3e34e47140460ff',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304302?gameHash=617f3af3e7d2ab4d',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130696?gameHash=532d412c3f38c0c5',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304324?gameHash=01bf1a7465a412ba',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130709?gameHash=1491ee8228ad66ec',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304356?gameHash=fc584c5143087c0b',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304374?gameHash=175112ba57cbce5e',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304391?gameHash=72ad86120a14eb54',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304399?gameHash=2536b98ac19e617d',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304412?gameHash=a30a480459e9151c',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1294710?gameHash=0d01dd80aa803997',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1294725?gameHash=3ae63821918e2b43',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1294738?gameHash=5fd20a0eec2c86f4',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304487?gameHash=0d5d1e4e719e8c46&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130723?gameHash=c5113e7f25839c2e&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304504?gameHash=fda4895c0bea1e8a&amp;tab=overview',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1294750?gameHash=fa9335e1a61165a5',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130734?gameHash=88de231d14ea4b07&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304521?gameHash=b70af7bde6c54520&amp;tab=overview',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1294784?gameHash=7d1bf4754cda9b46',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130739?gameHash=4ddb470392dd9248&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304544?gameHash=b14635dac9add7b4&amp;tab=overview',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1294813?gameHash=51f4579db6e7049f',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130748?gameHash=8f544ac73c53a606&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304574?gameHash=a5dcde67b90f29e3&amp;tab=overview',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304609?gameHash=7a5a6778a7074f09',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304635?gameHash=4cda5972cf8dd6bd',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304671?gameHash=67e29eccbbc8f667',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304691?gameHash=1572b2bb76b73da1',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304700?gameHash=b50bc9265ac35f9f',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304739?gameHash=b80bb99cbce5bd71',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304768?gameHash=6ed6e9d7108f27e0',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304785?gameHash=13054e8f14fcae76',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304794?gameHash=b4c27881f0c4481c',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304884?gameHash=29e8f7f002108b46',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304889?gameHash=7774d22665d9526d',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304894?gameHash=bac5c580914f7aaa',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1304928?gameHash=b8b029b3d4002fbc',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT04/1130793?gameHash=a3f6e45612b56302',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1295356?gameHash=731afc76037bd245',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1295369?gameHash=e743122ca08b77d8',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1295383?gameHash=072ee1028f03f4c9',
 'http://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1295402?gameHash=560c984fc1ba1168',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1295440?gameHash=32cdbf5ce1441159&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1295467?gameHash=bcc21c92fa78e889&amp;tab=overview',
 'https://matchhistory.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/#match-details/ESPORTSTMNT01/1295489?gameHash=95386dea5cf1ab09&amp;tab=overview']
```

Comment: Hi. Basically, you need to create a function and then use the .apply function. You might want to search SO for "dataframe add column using function" . Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886653/pandas-create-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns-apply-a-function-o

Comment: There isn't a way to do the swap in place? I need to generate a new column?

Comment: It's quite easy to do in place. I suggested the add column so you can see the results. Once the new column is what you'd like, you can tweak your code to replace the existing column.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas create new column based on values from other columns / apply a function of multiple columns, row-wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886653/pandas-create-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns-apply-a-function-o). Note that `str`s are immutable objects. Any modification will actually create a new copy of `str` anyway. So just replace the old column with the new one you generate by `.apply()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Basic Solution

The below solution makes use of a `lambda` function defined within a call to [`pandas.DataFrame.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

```py
df['url'] = df['url'].apply(lambda x: x if len(x) == 108 else x[:-10])
```

Here, each value within `df['url']` (`x`) remains the same if `len(x) == 108`, otherwise it is updated to be `x[:-10]`.

#### Handling Exceptions

The below solution is similar to that provided above, however in this case some basic exception handling has been implemented within the `url_trim()` function called by `pandas.DataFrame.apply()`.

This is more robust than the first solution and will not halt code execution when an exception is thrown within `pandas.DataFrame.apply()` due to unexpected values within `df['url']` rows, in these cases the value is simply left unchanged - for example if `numpy.nan` is used for null values.

```py
def url_trim(x):
    try:
        if len(x) != 108:
            return x[:-10]
        else:
            return x
    except:
        return x

df['url'] = df['url'].apply(lambda x: url_trim(x))
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code will check the length of the url  columns and prune of last 10 characters of the string if the string is below 108.The modified url will be included in modified_url column.

```
# Get string length
df["string_length"] = df["url"].astype(str).str.len()

# Create a filter based on string length
filter_length = df["string_length"]<108 

# Extract string for the filter
df["modified_url"]=df["url"]
df.loc[filter_length,"modified_url"]=df[filter_length]["url"].astype(str).str[:-10]
```