# Convert integer column to categorical label in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with an integer column representing severity values `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. I wish to convert this to an enumerated column with descriptive labels `[Critical, High, Medium, Low]`. Adding a new column as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26887820/813976) works, but I'd like to do this mapping **in-place** as I have a few more columns to be converted.

i.e. Convert this:

```
  Severity
0 1
1 2
2 1
...
```

to this:

```
  Severity
0 Critical
1 High
2 Critical
...
```

What is the best way to achieve this in Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = ['Critical', 'High', 'Medium', 'Low']

df['Severity'] = df['Severity'].map(dict(zip(a, b))
```

Or:

```
df['Severity'] = df['Severity'].map(dict(enumerate(b, 1))
```