# Row by row calculation

Tags: python

Dumb question, but I am a bit rusty in Python. So I wrote the following code:

```
df = pd.read_csv(mypath )
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Age'] < 2:
        Total = row['Input'] * 1.2
    elif row['Age'] > 8:
        Total = row['Input'] * 1.1
    else:
        Total = row['Input'] * 0.9
    print(Total)
```

I have a table and I am looking to some simple calculations using variables from each row.

Example table:

```
Input     Age     Total
-----------------------
100       5       
150       3
```

So, for now I am wondering how to take each row, do my calculations, and write it down on my total ( for each row). For example for the first row the total should be 90.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26887820/13145954) answer your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the apply method

```
def age_total(x):
    if x < 2:
        return * 1.2
    elif x > 8:
        return x * 1.1
    else:
        return x * 0.9

df['Total']= df['age'].apply(age_total)
```

Comment: That makes sense, but whenever I try to go into a column like df['Age']. it gives me an error. And I don't know why.

Comment: Nvm, it is because I forgot to add delimeter to read_csv. Thanks.