# Applying a function to a list in a dataframe and create a new column with results

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, numpy

I've got a dataframe like below with 66,000 rows..

| Client | Nodes |
| --- | --- |
| Client A | [987673, 932132, 3132131, 3123443, ...] |
| Client B | [4324234, 56345, 5435345, 5345345, ...] |

What I need to do is run the below function on the list within each row and then put the result in a new column.

I've tried using the .apply function but not sure how to loop it through the list

```
RouteNodeLL = []

for node in route_nodes:
    response_xml = requests.get(f'https://api.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/node/{node}')
    response_xml_as_string = response_xml.content
    responseXml = ET.fromstring(response_xml_as_string)
    for child in responseXml.iter('node'):
        RouteNodeLL.append((float(child.attrib['lat']), float(child.attrib['lon'])))
```

Comment: Duplicate for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886653/pandas-create-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns-apply-a-function-o

Comment: But how do I apply that to a list within a dataframe row? that's my problem

Comment: Iterate `row.Nodes` @DRobins

Comment: Create a function prototype that takes a row, in that function you can access the row column (nodes) using `row.Nodes`. The function prototype should have row since that is what is inputted in the lambda. `def func_lambda(row)`.

Comment: It's seeing the column as a float though and not a list, i'm getting a typeerror

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the code in your snippet is actually enclosed in a function you should be able to use `.apply` as follows.

If that I have a DataFrame

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Client': ['Client A', 'Client B'],
    'Nodes': [[987673, 932132, 3132131, 3123443], [4324234, 56345, 5435345, 5345345]]
})
```

And I want to compute some value based on the list in each row (trivially the sum), I can define a function to compute the value

```py
def my_fun(entry_list):
  return sum(entry_list)
```

and apply the function to the column containing the list to create the new desired column.

```py
df['Result'] = df['Nodes'].apply(my_fun)
```

If this doesn't work please provide more context, like the actual function.

Comment: This is my intention, but when I try the above i'm getting an "TypeError: ("'float' object is not iterable" error as it's not seeing the nodes as a list

Comment: I need more context here, can you send the error trace? I would useful to know which line is triggering the error. Also is the code above the whole implementation of your function? I don't see the `def` and the `return`.