# Python - Using row Series from iterrows()

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use iterrows() for a DataFrame... The Column could have a value such as Fred,William,John and I want to count how many names are listed. The following code works great...

```
for index, row in search_df:
     print(len(row["Name"].split(",")))
```

However, when I try to actually use the value from len(), it will give me errors... Such as:

```
for index, row in search_df:
    row["Number of Names"] = len(row["Name"].split(","))
```

That will give me an error.. 'float' object has no attribute 'split' or something..

And when I do:

```
    row["Number of Names"] = len(row["Name"].str.split(","))
```

It will give the error: `'str' object has no attribute 'str'`

Looks like a string, but it's a float... Try to treat it as a string, it's already a string... Frustration...

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please have a look at [How to make good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and [edit] your question to provide a sample input and expected output so that we can better understand your task

Comment: `row["Number of Names"] = len(row["Name"].split(",")) ………… 'float' object has no attribute 'split'` - this sounds like a misplaced parenthese ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on dataframe, try this:

```
df[“Name”].value_counts()
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to answer the question asked. Can you expand a little on how this solves the problem of assigning length values to a column in the given row while using iterrows?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.. I worked it out...

```
for index, row in search_df:
    num_language = len(str(row["Language"]).split(","))
    search_df.loc[index, "Number of Names"] = num_language
```

Comment: You should use `search_df.apply` for this, not a loop

Comment: OneCricketeer: Well, that's the thing though.. There could be 10 rows and under the Language column for each row, you can have a number of names grouped together. How else would I check each row of values and update the Number of Languages column for each specific row?

Comment: The function is applied column-wise. Refer my answer

Answer (score 0):

Dont use a loop

Refer - [pandas create new column based on values from other columns / apply a function of multiple columns, row-wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886653/pandas-create-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns-apply-a-function-o)

```
def count_names(row):
  return len(row['Name'].split(','))

df["Number of Names"] = df.apply(count_names, axis=1)
```

Comment: Ah, okay.. I see now.. Thanks muchly.. Have to say that looks a whole lot cleaner.. heh

Answer (score 0):

Splitting on `,` and then counting the elements seems inefficient to me. You can use `count` instead.

```
search_df['Name'].apply(lambda x: str(x).count(',')+1)
```