# How to change numeric values in a dataframe column to specific values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

I am trying to convert a set of numeric identifier values for a column in a dataframe into a string value.

`new_housing.replace({'borough': {'1':'Manhattan', '2':'Bronx', '3':'Brooklyn', '4':'Queens', '5':'Staten Island'}})`

I have tried using the .replace function but have been getting an error.

`TypeError: Cannot compare types 'ndarray(dtype=int64)' and 'str'`

I am fairly new to Python coding and it seems like this may be an issue related to the datatype in the column.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you have a reproducible example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas create new column based on values from other columns / apply a function of multiple columns, row-wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886653/pandas-create-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns-apply-a-function-o)

Comment: Using the answer above, you could override the column you want to replace instead of creating a new column.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
boroughs_dict = {'1':'Manhattan', '2':'Bronx', '3':'Brooklyn', '4':'Queens', '5':'Staten Island'}
new_housing.borough = new_housing.boroughs.map(lambda x: boroughs_dict.get(str(x),x))
```

This will find the number of borough converted to str and ignore values not found.
If you know borough column has **only** valid number of boroughs (therefore no values to be ignored) you can use:

```
new_housing.borough = new_housing.boroughs.astype(str).map(boroughs_dict)
```