# Use multiple conditions to create a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe and want to create a new column in the dataframe based on certain condition.

The condition goes like this: if (column_1 >=5 and column_2 >= 10) or (column_3 >=6) then 1 else 0.

What is the most efficient way to create this equation in pandas.

copying the note from the comments to the body of the question.

I have tries this:

```
df['Flag']= np.where((((df['Column_1']>=5) & (df['Column_2']>= 10)) | df['Column_3']>=6),1,0)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried?  This is really just a one-liner.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] with sample input data, _code_ for what you've already tried based on your own research, and a description of what went wrong with your attempt(s)

Comment: I have tries this: df['Flag']= np.where((((df['Column_1']>=5) & (df['Column_2']>= 10)) | df['Column_3']>=6),1,0)

Comment: @adityam.honade please update your original post with what you tried, properly formatted as code, and explain why it doesn't match up with your expectations / desired outcome.

Comment: `df['Flag'] = df[(df['column_1'] >= 5 & df['column_2'] >= 10) | (df['column_3'] >= 6)].astype(int)` should do what you want.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas create new column based on values from other columns / apply a function of multiple columns, row-wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886653/pandas-create-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns-apply-a-function-o)