# Create new column in dataframe using multiple columns of different types

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame for the boardgame [Terraforming Mars](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/167791/terraforming-mars) on which I want to do several calculations in pandas. The df has columns for points accumulated through different methods, as well as the `game_id`, `player`, `corporation`, etc. An example df is shown below:

```
>>> df.columns

Index(['Date', 'Game', 'Player', 'Coportation', 'TR', 'MILESTONES', 'AWARDS',
       'CARDS', 'GREENERY', 'CITIES+G', 'Total'],
      dtype='object')

>>> df.dtypes

Date           object
Game            int64
Player          int64
Coportation    object
TR              int64
MILESTONES      int64
AWARDS          int64
CARDS           int64
GREENERY        int64
CITIES+G        int64
Total           int64
dtype: object

>>> df.head()

          Date  Game   Player     Coportation  ...  CARDS  GREENERY  CITIES+G  Total
0          NaN     3   1             NaN       ...     41         2         3     90
1          NaN     3   2             NaN       ...      6         8         9     78
2          NaN     3   3             NaN       ...     26         5        11     90
3          NaN     4   1             NaN       ...     44         6         2     97
4          NaN     4   2             NaN       ...     22         8         2     77
```

I want to answer several questions, most of which are pretty simple: highest scoring game, lowest scoring game, mean game score, highest score by a player, lowest score by a player, player who has won the most, play who has lost the most, best corporation, worst corporation, etc.

For `player who has won the most`, I want to add a column `winner` for each `game`. In order to do this I need to check

```
for each game get highest total and corresponding Player
add corresponding player into column
```

How do I do that? I have checked [pandas create new column based on values from other columns / apply a function of multiple columns, row-wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886653/pandas-create-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns-apply-a-function-o) but it does not answer this question, as it's not just a few `if` statements in a function. I know this is likely relatively simple, but it's not seeming to coming to me.

Comment: Are there gonna be tied-winners for some games? Or do the games have exactly one winner each?

Comment: It's possible there can be a tie, at least in point value. So in that case, yes, there can be.

Comment: I think you are searching for a `groupby` followed by an `agg`. Did you already find that while searching for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up using this function, which I wouldn't consider overly pythonic. It, did, however, do the trick:

```
def winners(df):
    
    '''
    Takes in a DataFrame and outputs a winners column.
    If there is a tie, it adds both winners to the column
    '''

    lst = []
    for x in range(df['Game'].max()+1):
        if x in df['Game']:
            lst_1 = []
            df_1 = df[df['Game'] == x].reset_index(drop=True)
            mx = df_1['Total'].max()
            win = ', '.join(df_1['Player'][df_1['Total'] == mx].tolist())
            lst_1.append(win)
            lst_2 = lst_1 * len(df_1.index)
            lst.extend(lst_2)

    df['Winner'] = lst
```

Using this, just run `winners(df)` and it will pop out a `Winner` column.