# Importing a dataframe into Excel without over writing functions using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Trying to enter data from pandas into an excel datasheet say columns a, c and d, the datasheet has columns with functions which are at column b and d. How do I enter data without over writing the functions in the columns.

- a    b    c    d    e
- 1  .  a2/2   .    .   c+d
- 2  .    0    .    .    0
- 3  .    0    .    .    0

In my data b and d have NaN value, how do I stop over writing b and d so the functions remain? (. = empty cells in excel)

I have tried opening the file and building a dataframe with just b and d to add to the dataframe but cannot do so as they are equations.

I want either to import the dataframe into excel without changing b and d, or be able to pull b and d out to add to the dataframe before importing into the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it possibile with pandas, but you can take a look at this package [Openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html).

With this package you can write signle cells value in a xlsx file.

Or you can calculate and append new columns in pandas, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886653/pandas-create-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns-apply-a-function-o) there is an example on how you can do it.