# if elif else condition to insert new data into the existing column

Tags: python

How to use the `if elif else` condition to insert the data into the existing column?

Example, if the `columnA = 'abc'` then `columnB` return `'123'`, if the `columnA = 'efg'` then `columnB` return `'345'`, `else` return `'0'`.

so based on the data it should be:

**if** the `Sale id = 'sale001'` then `Sale no` return `'clo sale'`, **elif** the `Sale id = 'sale002'` then `Sale no` return `'blo sale'`, **else** return `''`.

[image]

Comment: "Column" of what? Pandas dataframe? Excel file? Python list-of-lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an "existing column" for computed/derived values.

Write a function with that logic.

```
def sale_no(sale_id):
  if sale_id == 'sale001':
    return 'clo sale'
  elif sale_id == 'sale002':
    return 'blo sale'
  return ''
```

Iterate over your data to call it to add a **new column**... [pandas create new column based on values from other columns / apply a function of multiple columns, row-wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886653/pandas-create-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns-apply-a-function-o)

Comment: getting error message `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

Comment: That's not related to the code I've provided here, so I suggest opening a new post with the code you have. If you literally copied my answer, and don't understand the accepted answer in the link, then you must change to check `row['Sale id'] ==`

Comment: Got the correct result already. Facing another issue when put back to the data table. Will open a new post for the new issue. Thanks for your assistance @OneCricketeer