# Python DataFrames - creating a new column based on several conditionals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a challenges DataFrame from the Great British Baking Show. Feel free to download the dataset:

```py
pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rfordatascience/tidytuesday/master/data/2022/2022-10-25/challenges.csv")
```

I've cleaned up the table and now have columns of **series** (1 through 10), **episode** (6 through 10), **baker** (names of each baker), and **result** (what happened to the baker each week (eliminated vs still on the show)). I am looking for a solution that allows me to add a new column called `final_score` that will list the final placement of each baker for each series.

In english what I am trying to do is:

1. Count the unique number of bakers per a series.
2. For each series,
   for each episode,
   if `result == 'OUT'`,
   add a column to the DF that records the baker's final score. The first score from each season will be equal to the count of bakers from step 1. I will then subtract the total baker count by 1.

As am example, the number of bakers from season 1 is 10. In episode 1, both Lea and Mark were eliminated so I want 'final_score' to read 10 for both of them. In episode 2, both Annetha and Louise were eliminated so I want their score to read 8.

I've tried window functions, apply functions, list comprehension but the closest I've gotten is pasted below. With attempt 1, I know the problem is at: `if df.result =='OUT':`. I understand that this is a series but I've tried `.result.items()`, `result.all()`, `result.any()`, `if df.loc[df.result] == 'OUT':` but nothing seems to work.

Attempt 1

```
def final_score(df):
#count the number of bakers per season
    baker_count = df.groupby('series')['baker'].nunique()
    #for each season
    for s in df.series:  
        #create a interable that counts the number of bakers that have been eliminated. Start at 0
        bakers_out = 0
        bakers_remaining = baker_count[int(s)]
        #for each season
        for e in df.episode:
            #does result say OUT for each contestant?
            if df.result =='OUT':
            
           
                    df['final_score'] = bakers_remaining
                    #if so, then we'll add +1 to our bakers_out iterator. 
                    bakers_out +=1

                    #set the final score category to our baker_count iterator
                    df['final_score'] = bakers_remaining

                    #subtract the number of bakers left by the amount we just lost
                    bakers_remaining -= bakers_out
            else:
                next
    return df
```

Attempt 2 wasn't about me creating a new dataframe but rather trying to trouble shoot this problem and print out my desired output to the console. This is pretty close but I want the final result to be a dense scoring so the two bakers that got out in series 1, episode 1 should both end up in 10th place, and the two bakers that got out the following week should both show 8th place.

```
baker_count = df.groupby('series')['baker'].nunique()

#for each series
for s in df.series.unique():  
    bakers_out = 0
    bakers_remaining = baker_count[int(s)]
    #for each episode
    for e in df.episode.unique():
        #create a list of results
        data_results = list(df[(df.series==s) & (df.episode==e)].result)
        for dr in data_results:
            if dr =='OUT':
                bakers_out += 1
                print (s,e,dr,';final place:',bakers_remaining,';bakers out:',bakers_out)  
            else:
                print (s,e,dr,'--')
        bakers_remaining -= 1



Snippet of the result

1.0 1.0 IN --
1.0 1.0 IN --
1.0 1.0 IN --
1.0 1.0 IN --
1.0 1.0 IN --
1.0 1.0 OUT ;final place: 10 ;bakers out: 1
1.0 1.0 OUT ;final place: 10 ;bakers out: 2
1.0 2.0 IN --
1.0 2.0 IN --
1.0 2.0 IN --
1.0 2.0 IN --
1.0 2.0 IN --
1.0 2.0 IN --
1.0 2.0 OUT ;final place: 9 ;bakers out: 3
1.0 2.0 OUT ;final place: 9 ;bakers out: 4
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pandas create new column based on values from other columns / apply a function of multiple columns, row-wise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886653/pandas-create-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns-apply-a-function-o)

Comment: @FAB, Close, but I need to iterate through each series and each episode. I had tried something like this:
test_funct['final_score'] = test_funct.apply(lambda row: baker_placement(row),axis = 1) under my episode iterator but it didn't print appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following (`df` your dataframe):

```py
m = df["result"].eq("OUT")
df["final_score"] = (
    df.groupby("series")["baker"].transform("nunique")
    - df[m].groupby("series")["baker"].cumcount()
)
df["final_score"] = df[m].groupby(["series", "episode"])["final_score"].transform("max")
```

Result for the first 2 seasons (not all columns):

```py
print(df[m & df["series"].isin([1, 2])])
```

```
     series  episode      baker result  final_score
8         1        1        Lea    OUT         10.0
9         1        1       Mark    OUT         10.0
16        1        2    Annetha    OUT          8.0
17        1        2     Louise    OUT          8.0
25        1        3   Jonathan    OUT          6.0
34        1        4      David    OUT          5.0
43        1        5  Jasminder    OUT          4.0
70        2        1      Keith    OUT         12.0
81        2        2      Simon    OUT         11.0
91        2        3        Ian    OUT         10.0
92        2        3    Urvashi    OUT         10.0
101       2        4        Ben    OUT          8.0
112       2        5      Jason    OUT          7.0
113       2        5     Robert    OUT          7.0
123       2        6     Yasmin    OUT          5.0
135       2        7      Janet    OUT          4.0
```