# How to apply multiple conditions in a dataframe

Tags: python, data-science, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

I do have an issue while applying a condition and then applying a value to that particular values.
I'm new to this just practicing with dataset.
My question is I need to apply a bonus mark to those students who have secured above 77 marks for 'math'.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

I have used if condition to check if the mark is above 77 and then created a column giving bonus mark to those.
What I have tried is :The above image gives the values for those students who have secured more than 77 in 'math_score'
Now, I need to give bonus score to these students, what I tried is that I looped through each student and then wrote a if condition gives me an error as '

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Please help me to achieve this goal, do correct me too. [This image shows the result for the condityion, who have secured score more than 77](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCLXs.png)
[This is the error, I have got when I applied my condition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flx5S.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome Arjun, please read this topic ([How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)) and provide some reproducible data.

Comment: Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886653/create-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns-apply-a-function-of-multi)

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[`np.where()`](https://www.statology.org/np-where-pandas/)**:

```
import numpy as np
df['bonus']=np.where(df['math_score'] > 77,(df['math_score'] + df['reading_score'] + df['writing_socre'] + 10),(df['math_score'] + df['reading_score'] + df['writing_socre']))
```