# How do I create a Python Lambda lambda function to do this?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, statistics

I have a dataframe which has a mean and standard deviation and I want to create a lambda function, or some other method, to contain the 1% Value at Risk level.  The function for a scalar for what I want to do is `var01 = norm.ppf(.01,Return,Vol)`

The dataframe of the input data looks like this.  I want to add a row that is Var01 using the norm.ppf function above.  How do I do this in a lambda function so that it can do the calculation for all columns in the dataframe.

```
         Iter1  Iter2   Iter3   Iter4   Iter5   Iter6   Iter7   Iter8   Iter9   Iter10
Return   0.04    0.05    0.06    0.07    0.08    0.09    0.10    0.10    0.10    0.11 
Vol      0.01    0.02    0.04    0.05    0.07    0.08    0.10    0.11    0.13    0.14
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `apply()` for that.

```py
df["Var01"] = df.apply(lambda row: norm.ppf(.01, row["Return"], row["Value"]))
```

But be aware that this solution is not optimal in terms of speed. You could also get rid of the lambda and use vectorized calculations  for the whole row.

Check out [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73643899/2641242) for some background info.

```
df["Var01"] = norm.ppf(.01, row["Return"], row["Value"])
```

Comment: Thanks, this will never have to scale to a huge number of columns so I shouldn't have to worry about speed.