# Excel Cell Operation using Python

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to perform cell-by-cell operations in Excel using Python. It's easy to perform using VBA but not sure how can we leverage the same using Python.

I have the following data and would like to perform a read-and-write kind of operation. I hope you guys can help me with the same.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book("Database.xlsx")
ws = wb.sheets["Sheet1"]

for cells in range(len(Age)):
# Perform the row-wise operation.

wb.save("Database.xlsx")
```

| Name | Age | Income | Tax |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | 36 | 50,000 |  |
| Will | 42 | 80,000 |  |
| Rony | 34 | 40,000 |  |
| Phil | 60 | 90,000 |  |
| David | 32 | 28,000 |  |

In the above table from Sheet1 of the Excel workbook, I would like to read the cells one by one for the Income column, so let's say Cell(2,3) = 50,000 then **update in excel (write)** Cell(2,4) (Tax) = 500 (i.e.; 10% of Income).

Comment: with padas you don't need to perform it cell by cell, that's the advantage - vectorize the calculation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create new column based on values from other columns / apply a function of multiple columns, row-wise in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886653/create-new-column-based-on-values-from-other-columns-apply-a-function-of-multi)

Comment: No, it doesn't update the excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Your question is about the calculation row-wise. If you have problem saving the df to excel it's completly different question and not asked so far. Your current code overwrites the old file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the `xlwings` library in Python.

This code shows how to achieve this:

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book("Database.xlsx")
ws = wb.sheets["Sheet1"]

income_range = ws.range("C2").expand("down")

for cell in income_range:
    row_number = cell.row
    income = cell.value
    tax = income * 0.1
    ws.range((row_number, 4)).value = tax

wb.save("Database.xlsx")
```

This code iterates over each cell in 'Income' column and calculates the tax as 10% of the income then writes the tax to the corresponding cell in the 'Tax' column.

Comment: I tried above solution but i got an error message "[SpyderKernalApp] Warning | No such comm: " I tried launching Spyder from Anaconda and also tried changing preference -> ipython console graphics backend to inline but it doesn't work.