# How to use python_api_core library for long waiting operations in google apis

Tags: python, google-app-engine

When i try to apply callback to my google api's which takes some time for operation, i found google_api_core library for this (https://pypi.org/project/google-api-core/) .Went through documentation (https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/operation.html) but didn't get any proper info. Any forum where i can get info.

Thanks in advance

code as per doc:

```
operation = my_api_client.long_running_method()

def my_callback(future):
    result = future.result()

operation.add_done_callback(my_callback)
```

Comment: What information are you looking for? The information in the docs you posted are adequate enough. Subsequently, to learn more about callbacks, I suggest giving this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319074/parallel-python-what-is-a-callback) a read. Furthermore, for general questions regarding programming, I suggest also posting in [r/AskProgramming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319074/parallel-python-what-is-a-callback).

Comment: To add to what I commented earlier, I also suggest you to post on the [Google Cloud Developers](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-cloud-dev) group as you will get specific help more in line with what you are looking for.